# Check if character is a number in Prolog ? how to implement integer/1?

Tags: integer, char, prolog, atomic

How can I check if a character is a number in Prolog without using `integer/1` (HW)  ?

I can use `atomic/1` , but it doesn't help me much , since it also returns true

to anything but numbers .

```
2 ?- atomic(1).
true.

3 ?- atomic(asasa).
true.

4 ?-
```

Regards

Comment: The homework tag is [deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated). Also, does the teacher want you to write your own predicate perhaps?

Comment: @Keyser: Oh great ! paka ...

Comment: @Keyser: No he doesn't , he gave me something even more annoying to write , so I need to check if a char is a number for the bigger function

Comment: I don't know prolog, but if you cast a letter char to int (if that can be done), what value do you get? If letter are contiguous (like ASCII, for example), you should be able to check against that range.

Answer (score 3):

Use `char_type(X,digit).`

```
?- char_type('3',digit).
true.

?- char_type('a',digit).
false.
```

Comment: This  works in SWI-Prolog, but `char_type` does not seem to be available in GNU Prolog. Is there another solution for other Prolog systems?

Comment: Also watch out, on my system `char_type(X, digit)` returns true for `X = ²`, `X = ³`, `X = '٢'`, `X = '٣'`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what do you consider a number? Just integers? Hex numbers? In case you want to recognise just plain integers (`[0-9]+`) you can just convert the number to a list and then check if each member of the list is a digit:

```
is_digit(1).
is_digit(2).
....
```

Another idea is trying to add `1` to the number using `is`; but this will not always guarantee that it's an integer.